# Littlewood Offord for odd number of real numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics

One version of the Littlewood-Offord problem states that if $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are real numbers with absolute value at least $1$, then the number of sequences $\varepsilon_1, \ldots, \varepsilon_n$ with $\varepsilon_i = \pm 1$ such that
$$
-1 < \sum_{i=1}^{n} \varepsilon_i a_i < 1
$$
is at most $\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$.

This bound is sharp for even $n$, obtained by taking $a_i = 1$ for all $1 \le i \le n$. My question is about the sharpness for odd $n$. By taking $a_1 = 2$ and $a_i = 1$ for $2 \le i \le n$, we obtain that the number of sequences in such case is $2 \binom{n-1}{\lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor}$. However I couldn't find a better example for the odd $n$ case and so my question is: is this example for odd $n$ sharp?

Thanks in advance!